# Stored procedure and MySQL Variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hi i am trying to create a procedure that gets the ansID as a param and updates the "score" field in both the User table and Answer Table.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE UpVoteAnswer(IN _ansID INT)
BEGIN
SET @_userID = SELECT user_id from Answers where id = _ansID;
UPDATE Answers SET score = score + 1 where id = _ansID;
UPDATE Users SET score = score + 1 where id = @_userID;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;



Error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT user_id from Answers where id = _ansID;
UPDATE Answers SET score = score' at line 3
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Put the `SELECT` statement in your `SET` statement in parantheses.

Comment: Thanks man! Working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either

```
SET @_userID = (SELECT user_id from Answers where id = _ansID);
```

or

```
SELECT user_id from Answers where id = _ansID INTO @_userID;
```